# Using setTimeout one time in the code instead of twice

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This set of code is used twice:

```
setTimeout(function () 
}, 621);
```

It is used to prevent the cover from being clicked on until the video is ready to be played.

Can that be used one time instead of twice in the code?

That is all I am trying to do.

I want to know if I can use setTimeout one time in the code.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/efjwn8qd/

```
setTimeout(function () {
  const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

    function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function showCover(playButton) {
      const cover = playButton.parentElement;
      cover.classList.add("active");
      show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      showCover(cover);
    }

    const playButton = document.querySelector(".playa");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
  }());
}, 621);

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(0);
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {

    const playlist = "2VwsvrPFr9w";

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);

  }

  function play() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  return {
    addPlayer,
    play
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
  const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
  const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
  videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}
setTimeout(function () {
  (function iife() {
    "use strict";

    function coverClickHandler() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    }

    const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
  }());
}, 621);
```

Comment: my opinions are uses `config.events` instead of `setTimeout`, ex: if `onReady` is triggered, remove/hide the cover, if `onPause` or `onStop` is triggered, add/show the cover.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? As an answer.

Comment: Can you not just put the contents of both `setTimeout` functions within the same `setTimeout` call? You can do it like `setTimeout(function() { (function makeManageCover(){ /*...*/ })(); (function iife() { /*...*/ })(); }, 621);`. If you want both of those things to fire after the same timeout, then you can just put them in the same function.

Comment: @Sphinx I like that suggestion, can you show me how it would be written into the code?

Comment: @nullromo Can you provide that as an answer because when I try to do that I get an error message.

Comment: @buildingcode543 Sure, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the jsFiddle, cut the first `setTimeout` call and pasted it into the last `setTimeout` call, like this:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

    function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function showCover(playButton) {
      const cover = playButton.parentElement;
      cover.classList.add("active");
      show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      showCover(cover);
    }

    const playButton = document.querySelector(".playa");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
  }());
  (function iife() {
    "use strict";

    function coverClickHandler() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    }

    const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
  }());
}, 621);
```

and it seemed to work with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

anyway, i don't think uses `setTimeout` is one good idea because not sure how much time it will take for `StateReady`.

You should rely on the player state or event triggered to control the UI state.

**Solution 1**: ignore the click event of `playButton` until `playstate` is ready (you can get play state by api=`player.getPlayerState()`).

**Solution 2**: hide/disable `playbutton` initially, then show/enable it until `onPlayerReady` is triggered. Even you can easily change the codes to remove the cover automatically once `onPlayerReady` without clicking `playButton`.

Updated codes in [jsitor fiddle](https://jsitor.com/QTVj5OgWw)

```js
function show(el) {
  el.classList.remove("hide");
}

function showCover(playButton) {
  const cover = playButton.parentElement;
  cover.classList.add("active");
  show(cover);
}

function coverClickHandler(evt) { // solution 1: ignore click event until playstate is ready
  if (ytPlayer && ytPlayer.getPlayerState && ytPlayer.getPlayerState() === 5) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCover(cover);
  } else {
    console.log('state:', ytPlayer && ytPlayer.getPlayerState && ytPlayer.getPlayerState())
  }
}

const playButton = document.querySelector(".playa");
playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);

let ytPlayer = null
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let player = null;
  // playButton.classList.add('hide') // solution 2: hide/disable the play button first
  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(70);
    shufflePlaylist(player);
    // playButton.classList.remove('hide'); // solution 2: show/enable the play button once ready
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {

    const playlist = "2VwsvrPFr9w";

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": function (ev) {
        ev.data === 1 && console.log('onStateChange', 'playing', ev)
        ev.data === 2 && console.log('onStateChange', 'pause', ev)
      }
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);
    return player
  }

  function play() {
    player && player.playVideo && player.playVideo()
  }
  return {
    addPlayer,
    play
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
  const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
  const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
  ytPlayer = videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}
/* when container is active hide the svg */
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}
/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}
.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}
.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px); /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <svg class="playa thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="qe5WF4qCSkQ"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: player.playVideo is not a function at line 77 col 12 //// To Reproduce: Click Run, then the play image, do it repeatedly until the error message comes up.  //// How is that fixed? That's what I was using setTimeout to prevent from occurring.

Comment: checked the updated answer, it should work fine now.

Comment: I'm still seeing the error: https://i.imgur.com/EwVRlBW.png

Comment: you used solution 1 or 2? I couldn't reproduce it =. =

Comment: To Reproduce: Click Run, then the play image, do it repeatedly until the error message comes up.  inside the jsitor.

Comment: play image(the animation of the cover), not the video?

Comment: simple solution: uses `function play () {player && player.playVideo && player.playVideo()}`

Comment: After adding that I got this error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. https://i.imgur.com/REp4SJo.png /// How do I fix that? How would the line be written so that error doesn't come up?

Comment: this is one warning, not a error. uses `function play () {if (player && player.playVideo) { player.playVideo()}}`

Comment: That worked, adding that line in, how does it work in the code? How does it prevent that error message from appearing? It prevents this: "player.playVideo is not a function"

Comment: I didn't dig in too much, but the error you encountered it should be caused by the instance(=`player`) of `Youtube Player` is not constructed when `player.playVideo()` is called somehow. above workaround is check `player` is not null and `player.playVideo` is not null before invoke `player.playVideo()`. or better expression is `player && typeof player.playVideo === 'function'`